# Php laravel memory limit error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, out-of-memory

I am making currently migration from one database to another, project is on laravel so I am creating laravel command for this. I have one table with about 700000 records. I have created function with LIMIT and transactions to optimize query but still getting out of memory error from PHP. 
Here is my code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '750M');  // at beginning of file

$circuit_c = DB::connection('legacy')->select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_info');
$count = (array) $circuit_c[0];
$counc = $count['COUNT(*)'];
$max =  1000;
$pages = ceil($counc / $max);

    for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
        $offset = (($i - 1) * $max);
        $start = ($offset == 0 ? 0 : ($offset + 1));
        $infos = DB::connection('legacy')->select('SELECT * from tbl_info LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $max);
        DB::connection('mysql')->transaction(function() use ($infos) {
            foreach ($infos as $info) {
                $validator = Validator::make($data = (array) $info, Info::$rules);
                if ($validator->passes()) {
                    if ($info->record_type == 'C') {
                        $b_user_new = Info::create($data);
                        unset($b_user_new);

                    }
                }
                unset($info);
                unset($validator);
            }
        });
        unset($infos);
    }
```

Error is this:

```
user@lenovo /var/www/info $ php artisan migratedata
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 786432000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/info/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 75
```

Error is show after importing about 50000 records.

Comment: Then increase [how much memory PHP is allowed to use](https://www.google.dk/search?q=php+increase+memory)... If you have run out of memory then you have simply run out; buy more memory, or find a more efficient way to migrate your data.

Comment: I need optimization answer, because I have already optimized my functions using LIMIT and OFFSET, may be exists some other efficient way.

Comment: Can you try doing this in chunks of 100 instead 1000, per transaction?

Comment: Just tried, didnt help.

Comment: How about within `DB::connection('mysql')->transaction(function()...`, instead of `use($infos`)` you simply move `$infos = DB::connection...` in the transaction closure? It looks like some references still exist so PHP isn't freeing any memory at all.

Comment: But i am writing this `use($infos)` because I need to pass inside transaction $infos variable,  `$infos = DB::connection` - this is not the same I think.

Answer (score 1):

There is kind of a "memory leak" in here. You need to find out which of the variables is hogging all of this memory. Try this function to debug and see which variable keep on growing constantly

```
function sizeofvar($var) {
  $start_memory = memory_get_usage();
  $tmp = unserialize(serialize($var));
  return memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
}
```

Once you know what variable is taking all the memory then you can start implementíng appropriate measures.

Comment: I have tried but I cannot find memory leaks, variables are all time all the same size

`I c:96 Count c:128 Circuit c:840 Count:464 Pages:96 Max:96 Start:96 Offset:96 Infos:7120136 Info:7488 Info data:7392 New Info:28312
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 786432000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in /var/www/info/app/commands/MigrateDataCommand.php on line 358`

Comment: What about sizeofvar(DB::connection('legacy')) ?

Comment: Error:   [PDOException]                                     
  You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, laravel caches all queries, so just: `DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();`